# Unable to access Google Compute Engine instance using external IP address

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a Google compute engine instance(Cent-Os) which I could access using its external IP address till recently.

Now suddenly the instance cannot be accessed using its using its external IP address.

I logged in to the developer console and tried rebooting the instance but that did not help.

I also noticed that the CPU usage is almost at 100% continuously.

On further analysis of the Serial port output it appears the init module is not loading properly.

I am pasting below the last few lines from the serial port output of the virtual machine.

---

rtc_cmos 00:01: RTC can wake from S4

rtc_cmos 00:01: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0

rtc0: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram

cpuidle: using governor ladder

cpuidle: using governor menu

EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17

usbcore: registered new interface driver hiddev

usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid

usbhid: v2.6:USB HID core driver

GRE over IPv4 demultiplexor driver

TCP cubic registered

Initializing XFRM netlink socket

NET: Registered protocol family 17

registered taskstats version 1

rtc_cmos 00:01: setting system clock to 2014-07-04 07:40:53 UTC (1404459653)

Initalizing network drop monitor service

Freeing unused kernel memory: 1280k freed

Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 10240k

Freeing unused kernel memory: 800k freed

Freeing unused kernel memory: 1584k freed

**Failed to execute /init
Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel.**

Pid: 1, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64 #1

Call Trace:

[] ? panic+0xa7/0x16f

[] ? init_post+0xa8/0x100

[] ? kernel_init+0x2e6/0x2f7

[] ? child_rip+0xa/0x20

[] ? kernel_init+0x0/0x2f7

[] ? child_rip+0x0/0x20

---

Thanks in advance for any tips to resolve this issue.

Mathew

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have an script or other program that is causing you to run out of Inodes.

You can delete the instance without deleting the persistent disk (PD) and create a new vm with a higher capacity using your PD, however if it's an script causing this, you will end up with the same issue. It's always recommended to backup your PD before making any changes.

Run this command to find more info about your instance:
gcutil --project= getserialportoutput

If the issue still continue, you can either
- Make a snapshot of your PD and make a PD's copy or
- Delete the instance without deleting the PD

Attach and mount the PD to another vm as a second disk, so you can access it to find what is causing this issue. Visit this link https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#attach_disk for more information on how to do this.

Visit this page http://www.ivankuznetsov.com/2010/02/no-space-left-on-device-running-out-of-inodes.html for more information about inodes troubleshooting.

Comment: Fingers crossed that you're correct about the inodes but the problem is pretty early on in kernel init

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `Allow HTTP traffic` setting on the vm is still enabled.

Then see which network firewall you are using and it's rules.

If your network is set up to use an ephemral IP, it will be periodically released back. This will cause your IP to change over time. Set it to static/reserved then (on networks page).
https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#externaladdresses

Comment: Allow HTTP traffic setting is enabled.
The firewall ports are open
I am using a static IP

The main problem is that the CPU is showing a usage of around 100% almost continously

Comment: There's a kernel panic on boot which is more likely the cause of the problem.